# Nest.js cant't found relative files

Tags: express, nestjs

I have a nest.js project

everything works fine in windows

but failed start in centos 7

it turns out file not found

```
2 import { TempSignupExamCategory } from './../entities/TempSignupExamCategory';
                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/DTO/SignupInfo.DTO.ts:3:30 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './../entities/ExamCategory'.

3 import { ExamCategory } from './../entities/ExamCategory';
                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/DTO/SignupInfo.DTO.ts:4:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './../entities/ExamInfo'.

4 import { ExamInfo } from './../entities/ExamInfo';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/DTO/SignupInfo.DTO.ts:8:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../entities/GroupInfo'.

8 import { GroupInfo } from '../entities/GroupInfo';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/Services/barcode/barcode.service.ts:2:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './../../entities/ExamInfo'.

2 import { ExamInfo } from './../../entities/ExamInfo';
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/Services/barcode/barcode.service.ts:3:27 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../entities/GroupInfo'.

3 import { GroupInfo } from '../../entities/GroupInfo';
                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 62 error(s).
```

here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

is there any idea ?

thank you~

Answer (score -1):

i change entities to Entities solve my problem.